# Loading local html file in webView android

Tags: android, html, file, webview, local

I have to load an existing html file into a `WebView` that is located at this path in the file system:

```
/data/data/com.example.example/files/file.html
```

But, when the `WebView` loads it, I don't see anything.
Who can help me?

`WebView` code (assuming path is the path I've written above):

```
 WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

  File htmlFile = new File(path);
    if(htmlFile.exists())
    {
        webView.loadUrl(htmlFile.getAbsolutePath());

    }
```

Comment: Does htmlFile.exists() return true? If so what do you see in logcat?

Comment: htmlFile.exists() always return true... i tried to put a log into the if and the logcat show that log...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this, adding in a `file:///` and doing it a little differently:

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webview.loadUrl("file:///data/data/com.example.example/files/file.html");
```

Instead of this, however, you could just put the file into your `assets` folder in the source code, and then do this:

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file.html");
```

Answer (score 30):

The html file should be placed in the assets folder, which will belong in the root directory of your project.

So move your file to in case of eclipse

```
assets/index.html
```

In an Android Studio project use this folder:

```
/app/src/main/assets/index.html
```

Now use

```
WebView wv= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Comment: in my project there is not folder with the name android_asset

Comment: then create the assets folder

Answer (score 7):

You need to implement a ContentProvider to map local files to uris as explained in this link [how to display a local file into Android Webview](http://blog.tourizo.com/2009/02/how-to-display-local-file-in-android.html)

or you just load any html page from Assets folder like below:

```
 WebView wv= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
 wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/yourfile.html");
 wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
web = (Webview) findViewById(R.id.webview);
web.setWebClient(new WebViewClient());
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```