# load html file in webview in android

Tags: android, html, webview, load, assets

Hi i have a  html file in asset folder and load it in webview using below code it play sound file but do not load html file until i click the button 1 time more where is th problem?
Thank you in advance.

```
                final Dialog helploaderdialog=new Dialog(this);
                helploaderdialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                helploaderdialog.setContentView(R.layout.helploaderdialog);
                final WebView webViewHelpLoaderDialog=(WebView)helploaderdialog.findViewById(R.id.webViewHelpLoaderDialog);     


        //--------------End ActionBarCod-------------------
final Button BtHelpAppUsing=(Button)findViewById(R.id.BtHelpAppUsing);      
BtHelpAppUsing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        appusing="Play";


webViewHelpLoaderDialog.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/"+"appusing.html");

webViewHelpLoaderDialog.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // do your stuff here
           new CountDownTimer(300,1000){
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){}

            @Override
            public void onFinish(){
            // your code
                if(appusing=="Play")
                {
                    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(ActivityHelpAndSupport.this, R.raw.appusing);

                    player.setVolume(100,100);
                    player.start(); 
                    appusing="false";
                }
            }
            }.start(); 



        }
    });

helploaderdialog.show();

    }
});
```

Comment: You can load the file by giving path in loadUrl()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading local html file in webView android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873749/loading-local-html-file-in-webview-android)

Comment: yes i load the file but it not show in webview until i click the button again and audio file duplicate  play.