# Loading javascript online in a local html file in a webview?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

i have a html file saved in my internal memory which i am loading in my  android webview,but i want to load the javascript from the internet.

Following is the code.
    
        
            My first chart using FusionCharts Suite XT

```
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="chartContainer">FusionCharts XT will load here!</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

but the js file is not loading.Is this way correct?

Comment: Please, also show the activity code, where and how you are enabling Javascript.

Comment: As everyone said enable Javascript its true but make sure that you give the Internet permission that will be another reason for not loading the js file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading local html file in webView android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873749/loading-local-html-file-in-webview-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable javascript inside your webview. Do this inside your `onCreate` method, on the class you use your webview:

```
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WEBVIEWNAMEINYOURXML);
    wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Where you substitute `WEBVIEWNAMEINYOURXML` by the name of your webview inside your layout xml.